# The Order of Orthogonality

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products, orthogonality

I would like to show that $B\subset A$ implies $A^{\bot}\subset B^{\bot}$.

Note the meaning behind this: The bigger a subset, the smaller its orthogonal should be.
Let $x$ be in the complement of A. Then $\langle x,y\rangle =0$ for all $y\in A$. But since $B\subset A$, $\langle x,y\rangle=0$ for all $y\in B$. Is it true?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Note that meaning behind this, the bigger a subset, the smaller its ortogonal should be. Let x be in the complement of A. Then, <x,y>=0 for all y in A. But since, B is least then A, <x,y>=0 for all y in B. Is it true ?

Comment: Be careful about what you mean by "B is less than A": being "smaller" is not sufficient. Literally just write out the definitions and you'll have three quarters of the proof.

Answer (score 1):

$$x\in A^\bot\iff x\notin A\overbrace{\Longrightarrow}^{B\subset A} x\notin B\iff x\in B^\bot$$

Comment: Thanks your help.

Comment: Wish you luck!.

Comment: Why do you say that $x\notin A\Rightarrow x\in A^{\perp}$?

Comment: Since the definition of $A^\bot$ we are able to say so$$A^\bot=\{x\in U| x\not A\}$$where $U$ is the Universal Set.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your argument is correct and straightforward.

Although true on the level of set inclusions, one should be aware 
that the implication $\:A^\perp\subset B^\perp\:$ merely depends on the vector subspace $\,\operatorname{span}(B)\,$ being a subspace of $\,\operatorname{span}(A)\,$ (as implied by $B\subset A$), and not on the "bigness" of $A$ and $B$ in the sense of sets.

A note regarding terminology: $V^\perp$ is usually called "orthogonal complement" only if $V$ is a subspace, else $V\oplus V^\perp$ won't yield the entire ambient vector space.